# Debian Wheezy Login Loop

Tags: debian-wheezy, gnome3, login-screen, x-server, infinite-loop

Debian Wheezy, Gnome 3.

Today I rebooted my computer for the first time in a large number of months. Lots of changes in configuration have occurred since the last reboot.

When trying to log in through the graphical login screen after it restarted, the desktop appeared for a second and then the screen went black for a second and then the login screen re-appeared. After many attempts nothing changed.
I've had this happen before and so did the usual, made sure all of the files in my home dir were owned by me (via text login on tty1). Crucially the `.xauthority` file was okay. This didn't help.

I created a new user and then logged in with this user via the GUI and found that this worked. It is therefore a login problem on my user alone. There is nothing in my `.profile` or `.xsession` or `.bashrc` that could be causing a crash. I tried renaming these so they wouldn't even run and got the same problem.

After examining the `.xsession-errors` file I found the following errors:

`Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0`

`Fatal IO error 104 (Connection reset by peer) on X server :0`

`X IO error received (X server probably went away)`

The first of these three error appears many times. The last appears at least twice. Then near the bottom is this line:

`Received signal:15->'Terminated'`

Googling for these errors naturally produces lots of possible root causes.
This is not a graphics card or driver issue. The card is new, the drivers are correctly configured (NVidia drivers) and they all work fine with the newly created user. It's just my user that is affected.

How can I get back in?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the issue.
When logged in as the test user, through the gui, I started google chrome through the Gnome menu. Immediately I saw the same issue, the session ended and the login screen appeared.

I logged in to the test user again and did a `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable` and now I can log in as me without issue.

Presumably this is a chrome bug.

---- edit ----

It might not be a chrome bug after all. FreeCAD and Blender did similar things.
Chrome is back in and working fine after I uninstalled the nvidia driver with the `nvidia-uninstall` script, temporarily droped back to nouveau with `modprobe nouveau` (in a text terminal by this point, no proper gpu driver) and then followed the instructions for doing an install of the nvidia driver from wheezy backports: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Version_340.65_.28via_wheezy-backports.29
FreeCAD and Blender also work again too.